# Java program wont read Character

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here's my current code, I left out the first half of the program.  I am trying to use the switch case statement to determine whether or not to repeat my while loop, which this snippet is in.  Also, my IDE (Eclipse) will not recognize 'Asker' as a variable, and wont let me run or debug

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int Customers = 1;
        boolean Repeat = true;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String CustomerInfo[][] = new String[1][6];
        // i = number j = name k = hotel m = location n = date p = discount type
        String CustomerData[][] = new String[1][4];
        // i = stay j = pre cost k = stay length m = final cost
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Northwoods Hotel Reservation System");
        System.out.println("");

        while (Repeat) {

            for (int i = 0; i < Customers; i++) {

                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
                CustomerInfo[i][0] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Hotel");
                CustomerInfo[i][1] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Reservation Date");
                CustomerInfo[i][2] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter The Location");
                CustomerInfo[i][3] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Room Accomodations");
                CustomerInfo[i][4] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Discount Type");
                CustomerInfo[i][5] = keyboard.nextLine();

            }    //End I for Loop

            System.out.println("Would you like to add another Customer?? (Y or N)");
            char asker = 'y';
            asker = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

            switch (asker) {

                case 'y':
                case 'Y':
                    Repeat = true;
                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    Repeat = false;

                default:
                    Repeat = false;

            }    //End switch

        }    //End While
        //System.out.println(Asker);
        System.out.println(Repeat);
        System.out.println(Asker);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Customer Number\t\t" + "Customer Name \t\t" + "Hotel\t\t" + "Reservation Date \t" + "Accomodations \t" + "Length of Reservation \t" + "Cost" + "Tax \t" + "Discount \t\t" + "Total Cost:");

        for (int i = 0; i < Customers; i++) {
            System.out.println(CustomerInfo[i][0] + " \t" + CustomerInfo[i][1] + " \t" + CustomerInfo[i][2] + " \t" + CustomerInfo[i][3] + " \t" + CustomerInfo[i][4] + " \t" + CustomerInfo[i][5]);

        }    //End For Loop

    }    //End Main Method
}    //End Class
```

Comment: First thing, which is unrelated to your question, is that you're not following proper Java naming conventions. Variables should begin with a lowercase letter, so `Asker` should be `asker`, etc.

Comment: Secondly, you don't actually specify what your problem is... You should include the first half of your code too, provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You mention a loop, but the code you posted doesn't even include one. What results are you expecting and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: You need to use break in your switch statement.

Comment: Please include the first half of your programm so that we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: The intro of your question makes me doubt whether you've actually put this code into a method.

Comment: `Asker` is defined outside your loop

Comment: @Zephyr thank you for that tip, I often forget about that, I am expecting my scanner class to input a character into asker (not sure the correct wording) , which it is not doing, like it is for my keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: @Adeel ill try that

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have not tried to, am not fully confident with methods, and is not required for this program

Comment: @KyleMccoy, you should check the code you posted again. That will not compile due to several issues. Get the code to a point where you can run it as-is, and then determine exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: The `main()` method is also a method, so you're fine (at least in that regard).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen my discomfort is not with the main method, and when people tell me to put it in a method, I automatically assume that they are referring to methods additional to the main... Thnak you for your advice though, keeping it in mind.

Comment: Please do not make edits to your question that completely change its nature after you have received answers. The original problem was found and answered by bcr666. When you fix that problem and change the code, it invalidates his answer, which not only isn't fair, it's very confusing. If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Adeel provided the correct solution: You need to use `break;` in your case statements.

```
        switch (asker) {

            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                Repeat = true;
                break; // without a break here, it will fall through
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                Repeat = false;
                break; // without a break here, it will fall through
                       // but this one isn't as bad since it is the same outcome
            default:
                Repeat = false;

        }    //End switch
```

Comment: This was not the problem, it was actually the placement of the initialization of
    int 'Asker'

Comment: @KyleMccoy not according to what I see. It is three lines above the switch statement.